# What is output by the Seminole's twin alternator system?

Tags: aircraft-systems, electrical-system

The Seminole's alternator system is a 14V 70 amp system. I understand that if one alternator fails, the other one will be able to produce 14V and withstand 70 amps.

When both alternators are operative, will the system be able to produce 140 or 70 amps?

I guess just 70 but want to make sure!

Answer (score 0):

If those numbers are correct, and typically alternators like that are going to be wired in parallel to the electrical buses in the aircraft, that means, with both alternators operating, they can deliver a maximum of 140 Amps at 14V DC to any load drawing from the electrical buses, provided the fuses on the individual buses are capable of handling those kinds of loads.